# Why gather() is faster than for loop in asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Why first code is slower than second? (Only the definition of ret has changed)
This is a fragment of my code and in the full program, about fifty links are fed into the main function.

```
async def get(url, session):
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            resp = await response.read()
            print(f"Successfully got url {url} with resp of length {len(resp)}.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(url, e.__class__))


async def main(urls):
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    ret = await asyncio.gather(*[get(url, session) for url in urls])
    print("Finalized all. Return is a list of len {} outputs.".format(len(ret)))
    await session.close()
```

Second:

```
async def get(url, session):
    try:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            resp = await response.read()
            print(f"Successfully got url {url} with resp of length {len(resp)}.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to get url {} due to {}.".format(url, e.__class__))


async def main(urls):
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    ret = [await get(url, session) for url in urls]
    print("Finalized all. Return is a list of len {} outputs.".format(len(ret)))
    await session.close()
```

The first code runs for 1.5 seconds, and the second for 8-10 seconds

Comment: Your question states the first example runs slower but the timing values indicate it runs faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, you have a list comprehension that creates a list of ... *something* using a list of URLs.

In the first case, you create a list of coroutines, but don't execute them immediately. Instead, you supply all of them to `gather`, which executes them *concurrently*, completing once all the coroutines have completed.

In the second case, you create a list of `None` values, but each coroutine created by `get` has to be executed to completion before the next coroutine can be created. Using `await` schedules the coroutine for execution and allows `main` to suspend while it is blocked waiting on the coroutine to complete.

Comment: Thank you, do you know how to do competitive execution using a for loop?

Comment: @Paitor. Is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: @md2perpe, I wouldn't say. I'm just wondering how the gather() function effect is usually implemented using only the for loop. I assumed that this person knows the answer, but okay, since it's something wrong, the topic is closed